# Vuejs - vue2-editor not accepting all tags

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have implemented the vue2-editor, and here is the below code

```
  <div id="app">
    <vue-editor v-model="content"></vue-editor>
    <div v-html="content"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

export default {
  components: {
    VueEditor
  },

  data() {
    return {
      content: "<p>Some initial content</p>"
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* text-align: center; */
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

If the content is wrapped with `<p>` tag then the editor shows the content correctly, if it is wrapped with `<div>` tag then it throws an exception,

**Exception**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of `undefined` (reading 'emit')

Few more tags with same issue (`<title>`,`<small>`,`<span>`)

**sandbox link for reference**: https://codesandbox.io/s/liz23?file=/src/App.vue:0-553

Thanks

Comment: I found the same issue on GitHub, but the provided answer doesn't seem to work for me 
https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor/issues/63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-72533246-vue2editor-div-bug-z8qqp8?file=/src/App.vue

It looks that is a bug of the library, meanwhile it gets fixed you can use this workaound.

```js
import { VueEditor, Quill } from "vue2-editor";

const Block = Quill.import("blots/block");
Block.tagName = "DIV";
Quill.register(Block, true);
```

Refer to this github issue thread for more info: https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor/issues/63